# Mousehook works but crashes after some time

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, api, hook, mouse

I am a non-pro using Visual Studio-Visual Basic. I needed a mousehook and found this on the net and adapted it. It works very fine, but after a while it crashes. I don't get any messages although I used "Try-Catch".
Do I have to clean a thread or something like that ?

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Reflection
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports System.Diagnostics


Public Class Fare
Public Event MouseLeftButtonClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs)
Public Event MouseRightButtonClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs)
Private Delegate Function MouseHookCallback(ByVal nCode As Integer, ByVal wParam As Integer, ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As Integer
Private MouseHookCallbackDelegate As MouseHookCallback
Private MouseHookID As Integer
<DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto, SetLastError:=True)> _
Public Shared Function GetModuleHandle(ByVal lpModuleName As String) As IntPtr
End Function


Public Sub New()
    If MouseHookID = 0 Then
        MouseHookCallbackDelegate = AddressOf MouseHookProc
        MouseHookID = SetWindowsHookEx(CInt(14), MouseHookCallbackDelegate, GetModuleHandle(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.ModuleName), 0)
        If MouseHookID = 0 Then
            'error
            'MsgBox("yok")
        End If
    End If
End Sub
Public Sub Dispose()
    If Not MouseHookID = -1 Then
        UnhookWindowsHookEx(MouseHookID)
        MouseHookCallbackDelegate = Nothing
    End If
    MouseHookID = -1

End Sub

<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)> _
Private Structure Point
    Public x As Integer
    Public y As Integer
End Structure
<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)> _
Private Structure MouseHookStruct
    Public pt As Point
    Public hwnd As Integer
    Public wHitTestCode As Integer
    Public dwExtraInfo As Integer
End Structure
<DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)> _
Private Shared Function CallNextHookEx( _
     ByVal idHook As Integer, _
     ByVal nCode As Integer, _
     ByVal wParam As IntPtr, _
      ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As Integer
End Function
<DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall, SetLastError:=True)> _
Private Shared Function SetWindowsHookEx _
      (ByVal idHook As Integer, ByVal HookProc As MouseHookCallback, _
       ByVal hInstance As IntPtr, ByVal wParam As Integer) As Integer
End Function
<DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall, SetLastError:=True)> _
Private Shared Function UnhookWindowsHookEx(ByVal idHook As Integer) As Integer
End Function
Private Function MouseHookProc(ByVal nCode As Integer, ByVal wParam As Integer, ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As Integer
    Dim aa, bb, cc, dd As Integer

    Try
        If nCode < 0 Then
            Return CallNextHookEx(MouseHookID, nCode, wParam, lParam)
        End If

        Dim MouseData As MouseHookStruct = Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, GetType(MouseHookStruct))
        Select Case wParam
            Case 514

                    Globals.ThisAddIn.dort()

            Case 522

                    Globals.ThisAddIn.dort()


                'Case 516
                'RaiseEvent MouseRightButtonClick(Nothing, New MouseEventArgs(MouseButtons.Right, 1, MouseData.pt.x, MouseData.pt.y, 0))
                'Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Cells(1, 1) = "right"
                'MsgBox(Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.WindowState.ToString)
        End Select

        Return CallNextHookEx(MouseHookID, nCode, wParam, lParam)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("mousehata")
    End Try
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that you are just trying to find an example that works instead of learning to understand concepts to develop your own from scratch, then I'll share a mouse-hook solution that I written time ago.

Note that I stripped much (unrelevant)documentation from the original code because the character limit to publish the code.

As for note of interest, I developed an application where I used this code, the app keeps running all day in my PC, and it never crashed.

Please, try it.

Usage Example

```
Private WithEvents mouseEvents As New MouseHook(Install:=False) With
    {
        .WorkingArea = SystemInformation.VirtualScreen,
        .SuppressMouseUpEventWhenDoubleClick = False
    }

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    ' Install Mouse Hook on the System.
    Me.MouseEvents.Install()

    ' Start processing mouse events.
    Me.MouseEvents.Enable()

End Sub

Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) _
Handles MyBase.FormClosing

    ' Stop processing mouse events.
    Me.MouseEvents.Disable()

    ' Uninstall the mouse hook from system.
    Me.MouseEvents.Uninstall()

End Sub

Private Sub MouseEvents_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal MouseLocation As Point) _
Handles MouseEvents.MouseMove

    Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("Mouse Moved To: x={0}, y={1}",
                                  CStr(MouseLocation.X), CStr(MouseLocation.Y)))

End Sub

Private Sub MouseEvents_MouseLeftDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal MouseLocation As Point) _
Handles MouseEvents.MouseLeftDown

    Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("Mouse Left Down At: x={0}, y={1}",
                                  CStr(MouseLocation.X), CStr(MouseLocation.Y)))

End Sub

Private Sub MouseEvents_MouseLeftUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal MouseLocation As Point) _
Handles MouseEvents.MouseLeftUp

    Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("Mouse Left Up At: x={0}, y={1}",
                                  CStr(MouseLocation.X), CStr(MouseLocation.Y)))

End Sub

Private Sub MouseEvents_MouseRightDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal MouseLocation As Point) _
Handles MouseEvents.MouseRightDown

    Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("Mouse Right Down At: x={0}, y={1}",
                                  CStr(MouseLocation.X), CStr(MouseLocation.Y)))

End Sub

Private Sub MouseEvents_MouseRightUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal MouseLocation As Point) _
Handles MouseEvents.MouseRightUp

    Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("Mouse Right Up At: x={0}, y={1}",
                                  CStr(MouseLocation.X), CStr(MouseLocation.Y)))

End Sub
```

Source-Code

```
#Region " Option Statements "

Option Strict On
Option Explicit On
Option Infer Off

#End Region

#Region " Imports "

Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Reflection
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

#End Region

#Region " MouseHook "

''' <summary>
''' A low level mouse hook that processes mouse input events.
''' </summary>
Friend NotInheritable Class MouseHook : Implements IDisposable

#Region " P/Invoke "

    Protected NotInheritable Class NativeMethods

#Region " Methods "

        <DllImport("user32.dll", CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)>
        Public Shared Function CallNextHookEx(
               ByVal idHook As IntPtr,
               ByVal nCode As Integer,
               ByVal wParam As IntPtr,
               ByVal lParam As IntPtr
        ) As IntPtr
        End Function

        <DllImport("user32.dll", CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)>
        Public Shared Function SetWindowsHookEx(
               ByVal idHook As HookType,
               ByVal lpfn As LowLevelMouseProcDelegate,
               ByVal hInstance As IntPtr,
               ByVal threadId As UInteger
        ) As IntPtr
        End Function

        <DllImport("user32.dll", CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)>
        Public Shared Function UnhookWindowsHookEx(
               ByVal idHook As IntPtr
        ) As Boolean
        End Function

        <DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)>
        Public Shared Function GetDoubleClickTime() As Integer
        End Function

#End Region

#Region " Enumerations "

        Public Enum WindowsMessages As UInteger

            WM_MOUSEMOVE = &H200UI
            WM_LBUTTONDOWN = &H201UI
            WM_LBUTTONUP = &H202UI
            WM_RBUTTONDOWN = &H204UI
            WM_RBUTTONUP = &H205UI
            WM_MBUTTONDOWN = &H207UI
            WM_MBUTTONUP = &H208UI
            WM_MOUSEWHEEL = &H20AUI

        End Enum

        Public Enum HookType As UInteger

            ' **************************************
            ' This enumeration is partially defined.
            ' **************************************

            ''' <summary>
            ''' Installs a hook procedure that monitors low-level mouse input events. 
            ''' For more information, see the LowLevelMouseProc hook procedure.
            ''' </summary>
            WH_MOUSE_LL = 14UI

        End Enum

        <Flags()>
        Public Enum MsllHookStructFlags As Integer

            ''' <summary>
            ''' Test the event-injected (from any process) flag.
            ''' </summary>
            LLMHF_INJECTED = 1I

            ''' <summary>
            ''' Test the event-injected (from a process running at lower integrity level) flag.
            ''' </summary>
            LLMHF_LOWER_IL_INJECTED = 2I

        End Enum

#End Region

#Region " Structures "

        ''' <summary>
        ''' The POINT structure defines the x- and y- coordinates of a point.
        ''' MSDN Documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162805%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
        ''' </summary>
        <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)>
        Public Structure Point

            Public X As Integer
            Public Y As Integer

        End Structure

        Public Structure MsllHookStruct

            ''' <summary>
            ''' The ptThe x- and y-coordinates of the cursor, in screen coordinates.
            ''' </summary>
            Public Pt As NativeMethods.Point

            ''' <summary>
            ''' If the message is 'WM_MOUSEWHEEL', the high-order word of this member is the wheel delta. 
            ''' The low-order word is reserved. 
            ''' A positive value indicates that the wheel was rotated forward, away from the user; 
            ''' a negative value indicates that the wheel was rotated backward, toward the user. 
            ''' One wheel click is defined as 'WHEEL_DELTA', which is '120'.
            ''' </summary>
            Public MouseData As Integer

            ''' <summary>
            ''' The event-injected flag.
            ''' </summary>
            Public Flags As MsllHookStructFlags

            ''' <summary>
            ''' The time stamp for this message. 
            ''' </summary>
            Public Time As UInteger

            ''' <summary>
            ''' Additional information associated with the message.
            ''' </summary>
            Public DwExtraInfo As IntPtr

        End Structure

#End Region

#Region " Delegates "

        ''' <summary>
        ''' Delegate LowLevelMouseProc
        ''' MSDN Documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644986%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
        ''' </summary>
        ''' <returns>
        ''' If nCode is less than zero, the hook procedure must return the value returned by CallNextHookEx.
        ''' If nCode is greater than or equal to zero, and the hook procedure did not process the message, 
        ''' it is highly recommended that you call CallNextHookEx and return the value it returns; 
        ''' otherwise, other applications that have installed WH_MOUSE_LL hooks will not receive hook notifications 
        ''' and may behave incorrectly as a result.
        ''' If the hook procedure processed the message, 
        ''' it may return a nonzero value to prevent the system from passing the message to the rest of the hook chain or the target window procedure. 
        ''' </returns>
        Public Delegate Function LowLevelMouseProcDelegate(
                ByVal nCode As Integer,
                ByVal wParam As NativeMethods.WindowsMessages,
                ByVal lParam As IntPtr
        ) As Integer

#End Region

    End Class

#End Region

#Region " Properties "

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Handle to the hook procedure.
    ''' </summary>
    Private Property MouseHook As IntPtr

    ''' <summary>
    ''' The mouse hook delegate.
    ''' </summary>
    Private Property MouseHookDelegate As NativeMethods.LowLevelMouseProcDelegate

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Determines whether the Hook is installed.
    ''' </summary>
    Public Property IsInstalled As Boolean

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Determines whether the Hook is enabled.
    ''' </summary>
    Public Property IsEnabled As Boolean = False

    ''' <summary>
    ''' ** ONLY FOR TESTING PURPOSES **
    ''' Gets or sets a value indicating whether to suppress the last MouseUp event of 
    ''' the specified clicked button when a double-click fires.
    ''' 
    ''' If this value is set to <c>true</c>, the application will send the events in this order for a Double-Click:
    ''' MouseDown, MouseUp, MouseDown, MouseDoubleClick
    ''' 
    ''' If this value is set to <c>false</c>, the application will send the events in this order for a Double-Click:
    ''' MouseDown, MouseUp, MouseDown, MouseUp, MouseDoubleClick
    ''' 
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <value><c>true</c> if MouseUp event is suppressed; otherwise <c>false</c>.</value>
    Public Property SuppressMouseUpEventWhenDoubleClick As Boolean = False

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Gets or sets the screen's working area.
    ''' The events fired by this <see cref="MouseHook"/> instance will be restricted to the bounds of the specified rectangle.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <value>The screen's working area.</value>
    Public Property WorkingArea As Rectangle
        Get
            Return Me.workingarea1
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Rectangle)
            Me.workingarea1 = value
        End Set
    End Property

    ''' <summary>
    ''' The screen's working area
    ''' </summary>
    Private workingarea1 As Rectangle = SystemInformation.VirtualScreen

#End Region

#Region " Enumerations "

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Indicates the whell direction of the mouse.
    ''' </summary>
    Public Enum WheelDirection As Integer

        ''' <summary>
        ''' The wheel is moved up.
        ''' </summary>
        WheelUp = 1I

        ''' <summary>
        ''' The wheel is moved down.
        ''' </summary>
        WheelDown = 2I

    End Enum

#End Region

#Region " Events "

    Public Event MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object,
                           ByVal mouseLocation As Point)

    Public Event MouseLeftDown(ByVal sender As Object,
                               ByVal mouseLocation As Point)

    Public Event MouseLeftUp(ByVal sender As Object,
                             ByVal mouseLocation As Point)

    Public Event MouseLeftDoubleClick(ByVal sender As Object,
                                      ByVal mouseLocation As Point)

    Public Event MouseRightDown(ByVal sender As Object,
                                ByVal mouseLocation As Point)

    Public Event MouseRightUp(ByVal sender As Object,
                              ByVal mouseLocation As Point)

    Public Event MouseRightDoubleClick(ByVal sender As Object,
                                       ByVal mouseLocation As Point)

    Public Event MouseMiddleDown(ByVal sender As Object,
                                 ByVal mouseLocation As Point)

    Public Event MouseMiddleUp(ByVal sender As Object,
                               ByVal mouseLocation As Point)

    Public Event MouseMiddleDoubleClick(ByVal sender As Object,
                                        ByVal mouseLocation As Point)

    Public Event MouseWheel(ByVal sender As Object,
                            ByVal mouseLocation As Point,
                            ByVal wheelDirection As WheelDirection)

#End Region

#Region " Exceptions "

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Exception that is thrown when trying to enable or uninstall a mouse hook that is not installed.
    ''' </summary>
    <Serializable>
    Friend NotInheritable Class MouseHookNotInstalledException : Inherits Exception

        Friend Sub New()
            MyBase.New("MouseHook is not installed.")
        End Sub

        Friend Sub New(message As String)
            MyBase.New(message)
        End Sub

        Friend Sub New(message As String, inner As Exception)
            MyBase.New(message, inner)
        End Sub

    End Class

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Exception that is thrown when trying to disable a mouse hook that is not enabled.
    ''' </summary>
    <Serializable>
    Friend NotInheritable Class MouseHookNotEnabledException : Inherits Exception

        Friend Sub New()
            MyBase.New("MouseHook is not enabled.")
        End Sub

        Friend Sub New(message As String)
            MyBase.New(message)
        End Sub

        Friend Sub New(message As String, inner As Exception)
            MyBase.New(message, inner)
        End Sub

    End Class

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Exception that is thrown when trying to enable a mouse hook that is already enabled.
    ''' </summary>
    <Serializable>
    Friend NotInheritable Class MouseHookEnabledException : Inherits Exception

        Friend Sub New()
            MyBase.New("MouseHook is already enabled.")
        End Sub

        Friend Sub New(message As String)
            MyBase.New(message)
        End Sub

        Friend Sub New(message As String, inner As Exception)
            MyBase.New(message, inner)
        End Sub

    End Class

#End Region

#Region " Constructors "

    Private Sub New()
    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="MouseHook"/> class.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="Install">
    ''' If set to <c>true</c>, the Hook starts initialized for this <see cref="MouseHook"/> instance.
    ''' </param>
    Public Sub New(Optional ByVal install As Boolean = False)

        If install Then
            Me.Install()
        End If

    End Sub

#End Region

#Region " Public Methods "

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Installs the Mouse Hook, then start processing messages to fire events.
    ''' </summary>
    Public Sub Install()

        If Me.IsVisualStudioHostingProcessEnabled() Then
            Throw New Exception("Visual Studio Hosting Process should be deactivated.")
            Exit Sub
        End If

        Me.MouseHookDelegate = New NativeMethods.LowLevelMouseProcDelegate(AddressOf LowLevelMouseProc)

        Try
            Me.MouseHook = NativeMethods.SetWindowsHookEx(NativeMethods.HookType.WH_MOUSE_LL,
                                                          Me.MouseHookDelegate,
                                                          New IntPtr(Marshal.GetHINSTANCE(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly.GetModules()(0)).ToInt32), 0)

            Me.IsInstalled = True

        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw

        End Try

    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Uninstalls the Mouse Hook and free all resources, then stop processing messages to fire events.
    ''' </summary>
    Public Sub Uninstall()

        If Not Me.IsInstalled Then
            Throw New MouseHookNotInstalledException

        Else
            Me.IsEnabled = False
            Me.IsInstalled = False
            Me.Finalize()

        End If

    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Temporally disables the Mouse Hook events.
    ''' To Re-enable the events, call the <see cref="Enable"/> method.
    ''' </summary>
    Public Sub Disable()

        If Not Me.IsInstalled Then
            Throw New MouseHookNotInstalledException

        ElseIf Not Me.IsEnabled Then
            Throw New MouseHookNotEnabledException

        Else
            Me.IsEnabled = False

        End If

    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Re-enables the Mouse Hook events.
    ''' </summary>
    Public Sub Enable()

        If Not Me.IsInstalled Then
            Throw New MouseHookNotInstalledException

        ElseIf Me.IsEnabled Then
            Throw New MouseHookEnabledException

        Else
            Me.IsEnabled = True

        End If

    End Sub

#End Region

#Region " Private Methods "

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Determines whether the Visual Studio Hosting Process is enabled on the current application.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <returns><c>true</c> if Visual Studio Hosting Process is enabled; otherwise, <c>false</c>.</returns>
    Private Function IsVisualStudioHostingProcessEnabled() As Boolean
        Return AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName.EndsWith("vshost.exe", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
    End Function

    Private Function LowLevelMouseProc(ByVal nCode As Integer,
                                       ByVal wParam As NativeMethods.WindowsMessages,
                                       ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As Integer

        If Not Me.IsEnabled Then
            Return CInt(NativeMethods.CallNextHookEx(MouseHook, nCode, New IntPtr(wParam), lParam))
        End If

        Static leftClickTime As Integer = 0I ' Determines a left button double-click.
        Static rightClickTime As Integer = 0I ' Determines a right button double-click.
        Static middleClickTime As Integer = 0I ' Determines a middle button double-click.

        If nCode = 0I Then

            Dim x As Integer
            Dim y As Integer

            Dim mouseStruct As NativeMethods.MsllHookStruct
            mouseStruct = CType(Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, mouseStruct.GetType()), 
                                NativeMethods.MsllHookStruct)

            ' Fix X coordinate.
            Select Case mouseStruct.Pt.X

                Case Is <= 0I
                    If mouseStruct.Pt.X >= Me.WorkingArea.Location.X Then
                        x = mouseStruct.Pt.X

                    ElseIf mouseStruct.Pt.X <= Me.WorkingArea.Location.X Then

                        If mouseStruct.Pt.X <= (Me.WorkingArea.Location.X - Me.WorkingArea.Width) Then
                            x = (Me.WorkingArea.Location.X - Me.WorkingArea.Width)
                        Else
                            x = mouseStruct.Pt.X

                        End If

                    End If

                Case Is >= Me.WorkingArea.Width
                    x = Me.WorkingArea.Width

                Case Else
                    x = mouseStruct.Pt.X

            End Select

            ' Fix Y coordinate.
            Select Case mouseStruct.Pt.Y

                Case Is >= Me.WorkingArea.Height
                    y = Me.WorkingArea.Height

                Case Is <= 0I
                    y = 0I

                Case Else
                    y = mouseStruct.Pt.Y

            End Select

            If x <= Me.WorkingArea.Width AndAlso
               y < Me.WorkingArea.Height AndAlso
               mouseStruct.Pt.X > Me.WorkingArea.Width Then
                Return CInt(NativeMethods.CallNextHookEx(MouseHook, nCode, New IntPtr(wParam), lParam))

            ElseIf x <= Me.WorkingArea.Width AndAlso
                   y < Me.WorkingArea.Height AndAlso
                   mouseStruct.Pt.X < Me.WorkingArea.X Then
                Return CInt(NativeMethods.CallNextHookEx(MouseHook, nCode, New IntPtr(wParam), lParam))

            ElseIf x = Me.WorkingArea.Width AndAlso
                   y < Me.WorkingArea.Height Then

                If Not Me.WorkingArea.Contains(x - 1, y) Then
                    Return CInt(NativeMethods.CallNextHookEx(MouseHook, nCode, New IntPtr(wParam), lParam))
                End If

            ElseIf x < Me.WorkingArea.Width AndAlso
                   y = Me.WorkingArea.Height Then

                If Not Me.WorkingArea.Contains(x, y - 1) Then
                    Return CInt(NativeMethods.CallNextHookEx(MouseHook, nCode, New IntPtr(wParam), lParam))
                End If

            End If

            Select Case wParam

                Case NativeMethods.WindowsMessages.WM_MOUSEMOVE
                    RaiseEvent MouseMove(Me, New Point(x, y))

                Case NativeMethods.WindowsMessages.WM_LBUTTONDOWN
                    RaiseEvent MouseLeftDown(Me, New Point(x, y))

                Case NativeMethods.WindowsMessages.WM_LBUTTONUP
                    If leftClickTime <> 0 Then
                        leftClickTime = Environment.TickCount() - leftClickTime
                    End If

                    If (leftClickTime <> 0I) AndAlso (leftClickTime < NativeMethods.GetDoubleClickTime()) Then
                        leftClickTime = 0I
                        If Not Me.SuppressMouseUpEventWhenDoubleClick Then
                            RaiseEvent MouseLeftUp(Me, New Point(x, y))
                        End If
                        RaiseEvent MouseLeftDoubleClick(Me, New Point(x, y))

                    Else
                        leftClickTime = Environment.TickCount()
                        RaiseEvent MouseLeftUp(Me, New Point(x, y))

                    End If

                Case NativeMethods.WindowsMessages.WM_RBUTTONDOWN
                    RaiseEvent MouseRightDown(Me, New Point(x, y))

                Case NativeMethods.WindowsMessages.WM_RBUTTONUP
                    If rightClickTime <> 0I Then
                        rightClickTime = Environment.TickCount() - rightClickTime
                    End If

                    If (rightClickTime <> 0I) AndAlso (rightClickTime < NativeMethods.GetDoubleClickTime()) Then
                        rightClickTime = 0I
                        If Not Me.SuppressMouseUpEventWhenDoubleClick Then
                            RaiseEvent MouseRightUp(Me, New Point(x, y))
                        End If
                        RaiseEvent MouseRightDoubleClick(Me, New Point(x, y))

                    Else
                        rightClickTime = Environment.TickCount()
                        RaiseEvent MouseRightUp(Me, New Point(x, y))

                    End If

                Case NativeMethods.WindowsMessages.WM_MBUTTONDOWN
                    RaiseEvent MouseMiddleDown(Me, New Point(x, y))

                Case NativeMethods.WindowsMessages.WM_MBUTTONUP
                    If middleClickTime <> 0I Then
                        middleClickTime = Environment.TickCount() - middleClickTime
                    End If

                    If (middleClickTime <> 0I) AndAlso (middleClickTime < NativeMethods.GetDoubleClickTime()) Then
                        middleClickTime = 0I
                        If Not Me.SuppressMouseUpEventWhenDoubleClick Then
                            RaiseEvent MouseMiddleUp(Me, New Point(x, y))
                        End If
                        RaiseEvent MouseMiddleDoubleClick(Me, New Point(x, y))

                    Else
                        middleClickTime = Environment.TickCount()
                        RaiseEvent MouseMiddleUp(Me, New Point(x, y))

                    End If

                Case NativeMethods.WindowsMessages.WM_MOUSEWHEEL
                    RaiseEvent MouseWheel(Me, New Point(x, y), If(mouseStruct.MouseData < 0I,
                                                                 WheelDirection.WheelDown,
                                                                 WheelDirection.WheelUp))

                Case Else
                    ' Do Nothing
                    Exit Select

            End Select

            Return CInt(NativeMethods.CallNextHookEx(MouseHook, nCode, New IntPtr(wParam), lParam))

        ElseIf nCode < 0I Then
            Return CInt(NativeMethods.CallNextHookEx(MouseHook, nCode, New IntPtr(wParam), lParam))

        Else ' nCode > 0
            Return CInt(NativeMethods.CallNextHookEx(MouseHook, nCode, New IntPtr(wParam), lParam))

        End If

    End Function

#End Region

#Region "IDisposable Support"

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Flag to detect redundant calls at <see cref="Dispose"/> method.
    ''' </summary>
    Private disposedValue As Boolean

    Protected Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)

        Me.IsEnabled = False

        If Not Me.disposedValue Then

            If disposing Then ' Dispose managed state (managed objects).

            Else ' Free unmanaged resources (unmanaged objects).
                NativeMethods.UnhookWindowsHookEx(Me.MouseHook)

            End If

        End If

        Me.disposedValue = True

    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub Finalize()

        ' Do not change this code. Put cleanup code in method: Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)

        Me.Dispose(disposing:=False)
        MyBase.Finalize()

    End Sub

    Private Sub Dispose() Implements IDisposable.Dispose

        ' Do not change this code. Put cleanup code in method: Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)

        Me.Dispose(disposing:=True)
        GC.SuppressFinalize(obj:=Me)

    End Sub

#End Region

End Class

#End Region
```

Comment: you didnt like `aa, bb, cc, dd`??

Comment: Just was funny to see that :P

Comment: :) Ok people, my code is not finished, I'll get rid of the integers later. But thank you very much for the answer, it is 6:30 am here, I'll test it after some sleep. It would be a huge step for my application if it would, so thanks again.

Comment: @Mehmet Keskin Then excuse me for the aa,bb,etc, I thinked it was part of the example you've taken from the net. I better will remove that from my answer. I hope you will not get a crash using the code I provided, I never got a crash or hang using it. (sorry for my bad english)

Comment: You don't have to, it's ok. Your code is very important for me if it works

Comment: The code worked, thank you for your help. Unfortunately the cause of the crash wasn't the mouse because it still crashes. I have to inspect the other  API.